# One leg is 90v the other 140v

Tags: electrical, voltage

When under load I’m getting 90v on one leg and 140v on the other Al thought it varies. If I turn everything off I get 120v on each phase to neutral. I think it’s the power company side, but they came out and said it wasn’t their fault that their neutral was dialed in…. And it is when there are no loads. Is it possible it’s on my side? I changed out breakers, I’m checking outlets and connections. I don’t have a sub panel, but I do have a jbox with a ground bar. None of the neutrals are in that bar - they run separate to the box. I only had one ground rod but added another and re ran the ground.

Comment: Possible it is on your side.  The power company probably only checked neutral to the meter, but not neutral from the meter to the panel(your problem/responsibility).  Can you explain jbox with grounds?  The panel should have a big ground wire to the ground rod/s, not a separate jbox for grounds.

Comment: Meter to panel connections are live.  Do not touch unless trained on live power or have power company turn off your power.

Comment: Where are you making the measurement?  At the switch board or an outlet?

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms strongly suggest a failing neutral.  And it will be failing at some point *before* where you are measuring the imbalance.  A failing neutral on one circuit would not affect the voltages on other circuits.